# Separate a single string into two

Tags: java, string

I am having a `String` like `test,test1`. I need to take out these two string separately. How will I read test and test1 without comma?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] parts = yourString.split(",");
```

`parts[0]` will then contain `"test"` and `parts[1]` will contain `"test1"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use split function OR StringTokenizer function defined in java.lang.String class.

Example 1 :

```
 String s = "test1,test2";
 String[] strArr = s.split(",");
```

The above array will be having two elements with values test1 and test2.

Example 2 :

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer("test1,test2",",");

        while(token.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(token.nextElement());
        }
```

Regards,
Gunjan.